# how to access a window variable from a popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup

I already lost some hours trying to figure out how to solve a javascript problem. I have a JS function that opens a popup window:

```
function openSearchWindow(searchType, targetIdField, targetDescField)
```

and I set 2 properties to this new window:

```
var win = window.open(searchPage, searchType + "search", style);
win.targetIdField = targetIdField;
win.targetDescField = targetDescField;
```

Until here, everything works perfectly. In my popup window, however, I need to access these two variables I set previously: win.targetIdField and win.targetDescField

How can I access them? I tried almost everything.

EDIT - In time,

In the popup window I have a search engine actually. When user clicks in a result, there is a JS function that gets the ID and DESCRIPTION of the selected item and passes it back to the "opener" window, placing them in the targetIdField and targetDescField, respectively.

EDIT (2)

Once the search is performed in the popup (through a servlet) the popup's URL changes, but it's always within the same domain.

Thanks in advance.

Lucas.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried accessing them through `window.targetIdField`? If thait does not work, you could bind the 2 properties on the parent window (using `window.targetIdField` instead of `win.targetIdField`) and then access those from your opened window using `window.opener.targetFieldid`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, freaktm. Actually I did try it, and it didn't work. The point is that it's senseless to put this variables in my parent window since I'd have to create a property to each field (in the parent window there are some fields that will access the same javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest tou use setAttribute and getAttribute, since this is supported by every browser (that I know of).

```
//Setting the properties (in the parent window)
win.setAttribute('targetIdField', targetIdField);
win.setAttribute('targetDescField', targetDescField);

//Accessing the properties (in the pop-up window)
window.getAttribute('targetIdField'); //you might need to use lowercase letters...
//If that doesn't work you can try multiple things
this.getAttribute...
```

Comment: Thanks, dominicbri7! I did as you suggested, setting both attributes in the function that will open the popup. But then, I tried to access them in the popup:

var proptext = window.getAttribute('targetid');
alert(proptext);

and also using this.getAttribute... but nothing happens.

Comment: window is not an element. It doesn't have set or getAttribute. You need to use window.document.body to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`win.contentWindow` will give you access to the new window object.

Then you can use:

```
win.contentWindow.targetIdField = targetIdField;
win.contentWindow.targetDescField = targetDescField;
```

To set `targetIdField` and `targetDescField` variables for your new popup's window object.

Note that cross-window access is restricted to the same domain.

Comment: Thanks, Soubok. I did try your solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I still have the same problem on accessing those variables inside the popup.

Comment: is the pop-up (URL) in the same domain ?  cross-domain access between a window and a child window could be a problem.

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if those properties are lost because once the search is performed (through a servlet) the URL changes (to the servlet URL) but we're talking always about the same domain.

Comment: No. I already checked on the GlassFish console, but I'm almost sure that's a JS error. I actually implemented a "temporary solution" that works for the moment, but I do want this function to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a variable from parent window/opener window can be done by `window.opener.yourVariableName`